# sign comparison in OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, comparison, similarity, sign

i'm looking for some functions in OpenCV to compare and valuate similarity (basing on images  and keyword) among images with archeological signs like:

it's better to use an algorithm find sign boundaries or use SURF or SIFT algorithm? 
An histogram comparison is useful?

THere is any tutorial, example to implement something about that?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your images. SIFT and SURF are good for detecting points invariant to light conditions, scale  and orientation, so they probably work good for your purpose.

You can also use matchTemplate which is based on normalized crosscorrelation and you will get a value for similarity.